# Can you disable or organize searchkit searches?

Tags: groups, searchkit

Searchkit has become so powerful, we use it in place of reports for most things nowadays. This has led to a mess of a page. Luckily the search function has saved us a bit. However is there some way to hide some searches or archive them. Sort of how you can disable groups but still look them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a good feature improvement and it probably will come! I'd start of with a good tagging schema first. If that isn't enough, you could create another Search Kit Display + Form Builder for Search Kit itself (as it works now) and just add an additional tag filter (e.g. Disabled, Primary, etc) filter for how you want to categorize the search to limit down the searches you want.

This isn't a major difference over going to the Search Kit screen and then selecting the tag but helps if you have a lot of categorization already.
[image]

On the display, use the link : `/CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/search#/edit/[id]`

[image]